# Should #include <math.h> build when inside of extern "C" block?

Tags: c++

I ask this because I'm using the unity test framework and it apparently does this.

It compiles fine under GCC 8.3.0, but under Cadence/Tensilica xtensa XT-C++ version 14.02, it barfs with a complaint about template inside of extern "C" deep within it's libc headers.  It worked on a previous version of XT-C++, so I assume they changed something with one of their later releases.

Is this unity's "fault"?
Or is Cadence/Tensilica doing something wrong?

I assume their libc headers are using `__cplusplus` to wrap template definitions (which have to do with native DSP types), but they didn't contemplate the extern "C" case.

Anyways, before I go and castigate Cadence, I'd like to know who's in the wrong.

Comment: I would say whoever puts any `#include` lines inside an `extern "C" { ... }` block is seriously asking for trouble. But I don't know that doing so breaks any rules, *per se*.

Comment: `extern "C"` just means "use C calling convention and no name mangling for these functions".